# Spacevim does not have colors in Terminator

Tags: 16.10, vim, terminator

Spacevim doesn't have colors in Terminator (Ubuntu 16.10), but it does have colors in other terminals apps, such as Gnome Terminal, or XTerm:

[image]

One at the top is Terminator, and Gnome Terminal on the bottom.

They're both using ZSH with ohmyzsh addons. I've added `export TERM="xterm-256color"` to my .zshrc and it does report the same amount of colors as the other terminal apps:

```
$ tput colors
256
```

I've tried using the system color schemes as well using custom, changing the colorscheme in Spacevim - but nothing happened. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Update: update to Ubuntu 17.04 solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am author of SpaceVim, by default SpaceVim use true colors, you can add 
`let g:spacevim_enable_guicolors = 0` to `~/.SpaceVim.d/init.vim`. If it still does not work, please open issue in

https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim

or send email to me.

Shidong Wang
wsdjeg@outlook.com

Comment: Hi @Wang Shidong - I really appreciate your eyes on this. I've kept digging and it seems to me that it's Terminator that doesn't have working true color support. If I type printf "\x1b[38;2;255;100;0mTRUECOLOR\x1b[0m\n" in Terminator it's grey, however all other terminal emulator shows orange. I've read that true color came to Terminator after version 1.90, however I upgraded it to 1.91 and still having the same issue. Until I'm convinced it's not a Terminator issue I won't report it on your github. Thanks again!